# Change action and image src url's with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am parsing a form from another one of my sites using a php proxy. It is working fine but the form action and img src of the submit button url's are relative. How can I prepend the full http//www.domain.com/ in front of each of the url's in the form?

Edit:

Here's the form code once fed through to the new domain:

```
 <div style="display: none;" id="SubscribeForm" class="newform">

            <h5>Subscribe to our newsletter</h5>

            <form action="/CampaignProcess.aspx?ListID=27057" method="post" onsubmit="return checkWholeForm93426(this)" name="catemaillistform93426">

                <div class="form">

                <div class="item">

                <label for="CLFullName">Full Name</label>

                <br />

                <input type="text" maxlength="255" id="CLFullName" name="FullName" class="cat_textbox_small" style="background-color: #ffffa0;" />

                </div>

                <div class="item">

                <label for="CLEmailAddress">Email Address</label>

                <br />

                <input type="text" maxlength="255" id="CLEmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" class="cat_textbox_small" style="background-color: #ffffa0;" />

                </div>

                <div class="item">

                <label>Enter Word Verification in box below</label>

                <br />

                <div class="captchaimg"><img src="/captchahandler.ashx?ID=22791bf65054422cadeb4aea9390cfaa&amp;Color=DimGray&amp;ForeColor=White&amp;Width=160" alt="Captcha Image" /></div>

    <input id="CaptchaV2" class="cat_textbox" type="text" name="CaptchaV2" style="width:160px" />

    <input id="CaptchaTV2" type="text" name="CaptchaTV2" style="display:none;" />

    <input id="CaptchaHV2" type="hidden" value="22791bf65054422cadeb4aea9390cfaa" name="CaptchaHV2" />



                </div>

                <div class="item">

                <p>We respect your privacy and will never share your details.</p>

                </div>

                <div class="item">

                <input type="image" src="/images/submit-button-white-bg_07.gif" id="catlistbutton" value="Subscribe" class="cat_button" />

                </div>

                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://testsite.businesscatalyst.com/CatalystScripts/ValidationFunctions.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">function checkWholeForm50598(theForm){var why = "";if (theForm.EmailAddress) why += checkEmail(theForm.EmailAddress.value);if (theForm.CaptchaV2) why += isEmpty(theForm.CaptchaV2.value, "Enter Word Verification in box below"); if (why != ""){alert(why);return false;}theForm.submit();return false;}</script>

            </form>
</div>
```

and here's the jQuery I am using to try and change the action url:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('form').each(function(index) {
    var urls = $(this).attr('action');
    var dom = 'http://www.sampleurl.com';
    $(this).attr('action',dom+urls);
  });
});
```

All other jQuery functions are working well on the page so I know it is not an issue with jQuery itself.

Comment: If it is **really your** site - get **your** sources and put them in another project, without any parsing.

Comment: What do you mean by "parsing a form from another one of my sites"?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but I had to do something similar recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110954/how-to-use-php-to-submit-a-form-and-retrieve-a-file-from-another-site

Comment: Ok, one site is on a hosted CMS (Business Catalyst) and it has elements that are dynamically generated such as image captcha. So I can't just take the source and put it on my server. These elements will no longer work. It's a subscription form I will be placing on my wordpress blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well start of reading the original url

```
$('img').each(function(index) {
    var urls =$(this).attr('src');
    var dom = 'http://domain.com';
    $(this).attr('src',dom+urls);

  });
```

that will change all the image urls
might be another way but this works just as good

checkout here

http://www.jsfiddle.net/LewEB/

Comment: Thanks Breezer. But what about the action url?

Comment: just change the selector to form and attr to action

Comment: Thanks Breezer. Edited my original Question.

Comment: i just tested it and it works perfectly... if you use firebug you'll see it gets changed

Comment: Thanks for the help Breezer and sorry for my Ignorance (if that is the case) but on http://www.jsfiddle.net/LewEB/ ib the results panel I can not see the urls changed. I am right clicking in the 'Results' panel and viewing frame source and nothing is different.

Comment: trust me it's change you have to use firebug or similiar to see the changed code

Comment: what is the real domain tell me and ill show you that it works

Comment: @Jackson - you can see it's working by adding such line `alert($(this).attr('action'));`